# Redshift SQL Procedure to create tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to create a number of similar tables using Redshift SQL (PostgreSQL). I imagine calling a procedure like

```
call create_dc_table('table1');
call create_dc_table('table2');
```

and so on.
I think I've misunderstood how procedures work in this environment. I did this:

```
create or replace procedure create_dc_table(p_tblname varchar)
language plpgsql as $$
begin
  create table p_tblname
  (
    indent varchar(50),
    name varchar(32),
    datatype varchar(30),
    datalen varchar(30)
  );
end;
$$;
```

I'm expecting p_tblname to hold the value "table1" that I passed in so that it reads **create table table1**, but can I do that? If so, how? 
Many thanks.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-dynamic-sql

Comment: Or a user defined function? using scalar SQL? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure create_dc_table(p_tblname varchar)
as $$
begin
  execute 
      'drop table if exists '||p_tblname;
  execute
      'create table '||p_tblname
    ||'('
    ||'indent varchar(50), '
    ||'name varchar(32), '
    ||'datatype varchar(30), '
    ||'datalen varchar(30) '
    ||')';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

call create_dc_table('test');
```